# How do Swift 5.1 Opaque Result Types interact with older OSs (e.g. iOS 12)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5

In WWDC 2019 session 402 "[What's New in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/402/)", the speaker, when discussing the Swift 5.1 feature [Opaque Result Type (SE-0244)](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0244-opaque-result-types.md), mentions that the feature will only work on new OSes:

> Requires new Swift runtime support
>
> Available on macOS Catalina, iOS 13, tvOS 13, watchOS 6 and later
>
> Guard uses with availability checking when deploying to earlier OS releases

In Xcode 11, I don't get any build errors (or warnings) if I write code using this feature, when targeting iOS 11 and up. I haven't wrapped any of the code in `if #available(iOS 13.0, *)` checks. E.g.:

```swift
protocol Shape { }
class Square: Shape { }
class Triangle: Shape { }
    
func foo() -> some Shape {
    return Square()
}
```

and then calling `foo()` from some code in my app.

What happens if this code runs on pre-iOS 13 devices? Is the lack of build error itself an error? Is there a definitive list of which Swift 5.1 features require new runtime support, and thus a specific OS version?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is the lack of build error itself an error?

Yes. And it is clearly documented. As the [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_beta_release_notes) clearly tell you:

> Declarations with `some` Protocol return types require the Swift 5.1 runtime in iOS 13, macOS 10.15, watchOS 6, or tvOS 13, *but the Swift compiler doesn’t enforce this.* Running an app that uses `some` return types on previous operating system versions *might crash at runtime*... **Workaround:** Only deploy binaries that use `some` return types to iOS 13, macOS 10.15, watchOS 6, and tvOS 13. Avoid them in code that must run on previous operating system versions.

So, do what you are told: use `availability` guard or prepare to die.

**EDIT** This bug is now fixed, meaning that the availability of `some` return types is enforced by the compiler:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I missed that bit in the release notes!

Comment: How is that possible that the whole `language` thing(!) require `iOS13`?

Comment: @imike That's not what the question was. The question was: is this really an iOS 13+ thing, when the compiler doesn't say so? The answer was: yes. And now (remember, that question was asked in the very early days of the Xcode 11 beta) the compiler _does_ say so, so the case is closed.

Comment: That's just not fair for server-side-swift projects.

Comment: This is not about "being fair", there are technical limitations which limit the ability to backward support opaque return types. See: https://forums.swift.org/t/se-0244-opaque-result-types/21252/14
"Opaque types require additional runtime support, so you'll need to be deploying to an OS that comes with a Swift 5.1 runtime to use them. Adding where clauses in the future, however, should not require any additional runtime support, since the implementation is being designed to accommodate them."